# Ubuntu Software Center downloads something when installing from a .deb file

Tags: software-center, deb

I wanted to install winusb from http://congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html
I downloaded the deb file, the latest was available for precise(I amrunning 12.10)
I opened the .deb file(390 kb) in Ubuntu Software Manager and clicked on install. Then I switched to the progress tab and saw this. USC showed that it was downloading data of size 3.9 MB.
[image: winusb ubuntu software center]

Can someone explain? Was USC just downoading the latest updates and just showed that under the current operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possibilities here. First is that there are unmet dependencies that Ubuntu Software Center is downloading and installing first. The alternate (less likely) possibility is that there is a newer version in the repository and Ubuntu Software Center took it upon itself to use that version instead. (This probably isn't at all likely, I just really hate that program and will assume the worst).

a quick way to check would be to uninstall it, then run

```
sudo dpkg -i ./path/to/deb.deb
```

and it will only half-install if there are unmet dependencies. You can resolve these with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Edit:
Alternately you could uninstall it, clear your apt cache and then disconnect from the internet while installing it and see what USC complains about

Comment: Most likely it was just installing dependencies.  You can check the History tab to see what it installed.  USC should install the package that you gave it.  If there is a newer version in the repositories, it would be upgraded when you update software.

Comment: Dependencies it was. libwxbase2.8-0  & libwxgtk2.8-0 were being installed which are dependencies of winusb. Thanks!